# cache table advanced before executing the spark sql

Tags: caching, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are doing a POC to compare different tools including spark sql, apache drill and so forth. The bechmark dataset includes almost one thousand parquet files. For the same query, apache drill takes like several seconds while spark sql takes more than 40 minutes. I guess the running time for spark sql is dominated by reading files from disk. Actually, the POC aims at finding how long do the queries themselves take, we kind of do not worry about the spend in reading files from disk at current. We are wondering is there a way to cache all the tables at advance and then execute the test queries on these cached tables. We understand that cache is also lazy and caches data right after first action on a query. Our solution now is to use a dummy action and a dummy query to cache the table first and then execute the test queries.

For example:

```
table1 = sqlContext.read.load(path1)
table1.registerTempTable("table1")
sqlContext.cache("table1")
result1 = sqlContext.sql("sql1")

table2 = sqlContext.read.load(path2)
table2.registerTempTable("table2")
sqlContext.cache("table2")
result2 = sqlContext.sql("sql2")

result1.show() //dummy action
result2.show() //dummy action
```

I'm wondering what does the cache really do? As we know that cache is also lazy and it happens at the first action. Does it make any difference for using different dummy actions and different queries?

Comment: Perhaps a more generic way to phrase this question would be: "Using Apache Spark, if I perform an action that doesn't necessarily scan entire data set (e.g. `take(n)` or `first()`) after caching - how much of the data would be cached, if any"?

Comment: @Fihop this is a very good question. How did you solve it?

Comment: @Fihop Did you find any solution to this POC?